# High cpu usage when scrolling or moving windows Gnome in 18.04

Tags: gnome, cpu, cpu-load, hardware-acceleration

I have an AMD a10-7850k apu in my computer and I also have an RX550 GPU. I have the RX550 GPU set up to be passed to a windows kvm for games and that works fine. But On my APU using the radeon driver the performance when scrolling or anything moving is pretty bad and the /usr/bin/gnome-sh process begins to use quite a bit of cpu on one core. I don't know why this happens. I've tried the AMDGPU driver with the apu but it just shows a lot of corrupted text on the login screen and either doesn't let me log in or it does but the performance is equally as bad. Games do launch under linux but the performance isn't as good as usual and I'm kinda stuck on this.

Comment: Mine is Nvidia Geforce 660ti. I had the scroll problem on my GNOME in 18.04, 3 days ago! updated my system (Ubuntu base) and problem solved. Update your Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade and restarted and the problem is still happening, Don't think that was it.

Answer (score -1):

I have an RX580, so I was in the same boat as you. The problem was that Ubuntu had some Nvidia drivers that it was using. When it couldn't find an Nvidia card, it fell back to software rendering. Here is how I solved it:

1. Select the PPA that you want. (Default Ubuntu, Padoka, Oibaf, ect. I'm currently using the default.)
2. In the Terminal, type: `sudo rm /etc/X11/Xsession.d/50_check_unity_support` This will remove the 50_check_unity_support file, just in case. (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nux/+bug/1767468)
3. Finally, type: `sudo apt-get remove libnvidia-gl-390` It should install libegl-mesa0 as well as remove libnvidia-gl-390. If libegl-mesa0 does not install, install it by typing: `sudo apt-get install libegl-mesa0`
4. Reboot.

Tell me if this helps!

Comment: Sorry I never answered your question. I also never got to try it out as I use fedora now.